# Convert Pandas tseries object to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, resampling

I wish to convert the following `<'pandas.tseries.resample.DatetimeIndexResampler'>` type object into a pandas DataFrame object (`<'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`). However I cannot find the relevant function in the pandas documentation to allow me to do this.

The data takes the following form:

```
                  M30
Date                 
2016-02-29  -61.187699
2016-03-31  -60.869565
2016-04-30  -61.717922
2016-05-31  -61.823966
2016-06-30  -62.142100
...
```

Can anyone provide an alternative solution?

Comment: They function in essentially the same way.  A data frame is columns of data and an index.  A series object is basically a single column of data and an index.  What do you need the data frame for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need some aggregate function like `sum` or `mean`.

Sample with your data:

```
print (df)
                  M30
Date                 
2016-02-29 -61.187699
2016-03-31 -60.869565
2016-04-30 -61.717922
2016-05-31 -61.823966
2016-06-30 -62.142100

#resample by 2 months
r = df.resample('2M')
print (r)
DatetimeIndexResampler [freq=<2 * MonthEnds>, 
                        axis=0, 
                        closed=right, 
                        label=right, 
                        convention=start, 
                        base=0]
```

```
#aggregate sum
print (r.sum())
                   M30
Date                  
2016-02-29  -61.187699
2016-04-30 -122.587487
2016-06-30 -123.966066

#aggregate mean
print (r.mean())
                  M30
Date                 
2016-02-29 -61.187699
2016-04-30 -61.293743
2016-06-30 -61.983033

#aggregate first
print (r.first())
                  M30
Date                 
2016-02-29 -61.187699
2016-04-30 -60.869565
2016-06-30 -61.823966
```