# How to fillna() with value 0 after calling resample?

Tags: python, pandas

Either I don't understand the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) or it is outdated.

If I run

```
user[["DOC_ACC_DT", "USER_SIGNON_ID"]].groupby("DOC_ACC_DT").agg(["count"]).resample("1D").fillna(value=0, method="ffill")
```

It get

```
TypeError: fillna() got an unexpected keyword argument 'value'
```

If I just run

```
.fillna(0)
```

I get

```
ValueError: Invalid fill method. Expecting pad (ffill), backfill (bfill) or nearest. Got 0
```

If I then set

```
.fillna(0, method="ffill")
```

I get

```
TypeError: fillna() got multiple values for keyword argument 'method'
```

so the only thing that works is

```
.fillna("ffill")
```

but of course that makes just a forward fill. However, I want to replace `NaN` with zeros. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @AmiTavory This gives me "*ValueError: Invalid fill method. Expecting pad (ffill), backfill (bfill) or nearest. Got value='0', method='ffill'"* for `.fillna("value='0', method='ffill'")`

Comment: There's examples here.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#filling-missing-values-fillna

Comment: I had the same problem a few days ago. It looks like `resample().fillna()` only works with the method keyword. You cannot pass a constant. Not sure if it's a bug or designed to be that way.  The correct link to docs should be [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.fillna.html) I think as it's a different method.

Comment: @displayname IDK the answer to your question, but it actually makes sense that you can't specify both a value and a method (what would be the meaning?). Your failure for `fillna(0)` is puzzling, though.

Comment: @ayhan [This](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.fillna.html) might corroborate your point.

Comment: @AmiTavory Yes I was about to add that.

Comment: @displayname See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334343/convert-pandas-tseries-object-to-a-dataframe), which shows how to convert this type. After the conversion, you're back to the regular methods.

Comment: @ayhan Thanks for your help. To me it feels a bit like a bug to be honest. If it is then it won't be there long :D

Comment: @AmiTavory Thank you! I think for now I'll just go with `replace(np.nan, 0)` even though `fillna(0)` should do the same thing :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, I don't get why the code above is not working and I'm going to wait for somebody to give a better answer than this but I just found

```
.replace(np.nan, 0)
```

does what I would have expected from `.fillna(0)`.

Comment: Barring converting the resulting type of `resample`, this looks like the way to go.

Comment: Or you could have used `.asfreq().fillna(0)`

Answer (score 8):

I do some test and it is very interesting.

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=20, freq='S')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a'] * 10 + ['b'] * 10,
                   'b':np.random.randint(0, 500, len(rng))}, index=rng)
df.b.iloc[3:8] = np.nan
print (df)
                     a      b
2012-01-01 00:00:00  a   37.0
2012-01-01 00:00:01  a  235.0
2012-01-01 00:00:02  a  396.0
2012-01-01 00:00:03  a    NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:04  a    NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:05  a    NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:06  a    NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:07  a    NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:08  a  335.0
2012-01-01 00:00:09  a  448.0
2012-01-01 00:00:10  b  144.0
2012-01-01 00:00:11  b  129.0
2012-01-01 00:00:12  b  460.0
2012-01-01 00:00:13  b   71.0
2012-01-01 00:00:14  b  237.0
2012-01-01 00:00:15  b  390.0
2012-01-01 00:00:16  b  281.0
2012-01-01 00:00:17  b  178.0
2012-01-01 00:00:18  b  276.0
2012-01-01 00:00:19  b  254.0
```

**Downsampling**:

Possible solution with [`Resampler.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.asfreq.html):

If use `asfreq`, behaviour is same aggregating by `first`:

```
print (df.groupby('a').resample('2S').first())
                       a      b
a                              
a 2012-01-01 00:00:00  a   37.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:02  a  396.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:04  a    NaN
  2012-01-01 00:00:06  a    NaN
  2012-01-01 00:00:08  a  335.0
b 2012-01-01 00:00:10  b  144.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:12  b  460.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:14  b  237.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:16  b  281.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:18  b  276.0
```

```
print (df.groupby('a').resample('2S').first().fillna(0))
                       a      b
a                              
a 2012-01-01 00:00:00  a   37.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:02  a  396.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:04  a    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:06  a    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:08  a  335.0
b 2012-01-01 00:00:10  b  144.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:12  b  460.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:14  b  237.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:16  b  281.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:18  b  276.0

print (df.groupby('a').resample('2S').asfreq().fillna(0))
                       a      b
a                              
a 2012-01-01 00:00:00  a   37.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:02  a  396.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:04  a    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:06  a    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:08  a  335.0
b 2012-01-01 00:00:10  b  144.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:12  b  460.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:14  b  237.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:16  b  281.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:18  b  276.0
```

If use `replace` another values are aggregating as `mean`:

```
print (df.groupby('a').resample('2S').mean())
                           b
a                           
a 2012-01-01 00:00:00  136.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:02  396.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:04    NaN
  2012-01-01 00:00:06    NaN
  2012-01-01 00:00:08  391.5
b 2012-01-01 00:00:10  136.5
  2012-01-01 00:00:12  265.5
  2012-01-01 00:00:14  313.5
  2012-01-01 00:00:16  229.5
  2012-01-01 00:00:18  265.0
```

```
print (df.groupby('a').resample('2S').mean().fillna(0))
                           b
a                           
a 2012-01-01 00:00:00  136.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:02  396.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:04    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:06    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:08  391.5
b 2012-01-01 00:00:10  136.5
  2012-01-01 00:00:12  265.5
  2012-01-01 00:00:14  313.5
  2012-01-01 00:00:16  229.5
  2012-01-01 00:00:18  265.0

print (df.groupby('a').resample('2S').replace(np.nan,0))
                           b
a                           
a 2012-01-01 00:00:00  136.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:02  396.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:04    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:06    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:08  391.5
b 2012-01-01 00:00:10  136.5
  2012-01-01 00:00:12  265.5
  2012-01-01 00:00:14  313.5
  2012-01-01 00:00:16  229.5
  2012-01-01 00:00:18  265.0
```

**Upsampling**:

Use `asfreq`, it is same as `replace`:

```
print (df.groupby('a').resample('200L').asfreq().fillna(0))
                           a      b
a                                  
a 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000  a   37.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:00.200  0    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:00.400  0    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:00.600  0    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:00.800  0    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:01.000  a  235.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:01.200  0    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:01.400  0    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:01.600  0    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:01.800  0    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:02.000  a  396.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:02.200  0    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:02.400  0    0.0
  ...

print (df.groupby('a').resample('200L').replace(np.nan,0))
                               b
a                               
a 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000   37.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:00.200    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:00.400    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:00.600    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:00.800    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:01.000  235.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:01.200    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:01.400    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:01.600    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:01.800    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:02.000  396.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:02.200    0.0
  2012-01-01 00:00:02.400    0.0
  ...
```

```
print ((df.groupby('a').resample('200L').replace(np.nan,0).b == 
       df.groupby('a').resample('200L').asfreq().fillna(0).b).all())
True
```

**Conclusion**:

For downsampling use same aggregating function like `sum`, `first` or `mean` and for upsampling `asfreq`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you try to call the `fillna` method from `DatetimeIndexResampler` object, which is returned by the `resample` method. If you call an aggregation function before fillna it will work, for example: `df.resample('1H').sum().fillna(0)`

Comment: this would yield a result different to the original question. fillna(0) would allow the aggregation function to compute since the presence of nan would make the aggreation to yield also nan

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `sum()` for it.
Check out the docs at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.sum.html

Basically there's a `min_count` parameter, by default it's 0. This means that after you resample, if `count(nan) <= min_count`, then the value will be nan. However, since it's 0, by default, the value will be 0. So no need to replace or fillna.

In fact, if you wanted to fill with a value that's not 0, you could set `.sum(min_count=1)` then `.replace(float('nan'), 'whatever you want')`

Example below:

```py
import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-01-07', freq='3D'),
                       'value': range(3)})
>>> df
        date  value
0 2021-01-01      0
1 2021-01-04      1
2 2021-01-07      2

>>> df.set_index('date').resample('D').sum().reset_index()
        date  value
0 2021-01-01      0
1 2021-01-02      0
2 2021-01-03      0
3 2021-01-04      1
4 2021-01-05      0
5 2021-01-06      0
6 2021-01-07      2

# if you wanna replace nan with some other values, could also use replace() if more than
# 1 column to replace
>>> df.set_index('date').resample('D').sum(min_count=1).fillna(-10).reset_index()
        date  value
0 2021-01-01    0.0
1 2021-01-02  -10.0
2 2021-01-03  -10.0
3 2021-01-04    1.0
4 2021-01-05  -10.0
5 2021-01-06  -10.0
6 2021-01-07    2.0
```

Comment: this worked for me but I have no idea what is going on, or why we call sum here

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround close to using `fillna` directly would be to call it after performing `.head(len(df.index))`.

I'm presuming [`DF.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) to be useful in this case mainly because when resample function is applied to a groupby object, it will act as a filter on the input, returning a reduced shape of the original due to elimination of groups.

Calling `DF.head()` does not get affected by this transformation and returns the entire `DF`.

**Demo:**

```
np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2),
              index=pd.date_range('1/1/2016', freq='10D', periods=10),
              columns=['A', 'B']).reset_index()

df
       index         A         B
0 2016-01-01  0.496714 -0.138264
1 2016-01-11  0.647689  1.523030
2 2016-01-21 -0.234153 -0.234137
3 2016-01-31  1.579213  0.767435
4 2016-02-10 -0.469474  0.542560
5 2016-02-20 -0.463418 -0.465730
6 2016-03-01  0.241962 -1.913280
7 2016-03-11 -1.724918 -0.562288
8 2016-03-21 -1.012831  0.314247
9 2016-03-31 -0.908024 -1.412304
```

**Operations:**

```
resampled_group = df[['index', 'A']].groupby(['index'])['A'].agg('count').resample('2D')
resampled_group.head(len(resampled_group.index)).fillna(0).head(20)

index
2016-01-01    1.0
2016-01-03    0.0
2016-01-05    0.0
2016-01-07    0.0
2016-01-09    0.0
2016-01-11    1.0
2016-01-13    0.0
2016-01-15    0.0
2016-01-17    0.0
2016-01-19    0.0
2016-01-21    1.0
2016-01-23    0.0
2016-01-25    0.0
2016-01-27    0.0
2016-01-29    0.0
2016-01-31    1.0
2016-02-02    0.0
2016-02-04    0.0
2016-02-06    0.0
2016-02-08    0.0
Freq: 2D, Name: A, dtype: float64
```