# How can I plot my groupby() result?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, nan, resampling

I'm running a `groupby()` on my data like this:

```
user.groupby(["DOC_ACC_DT", "DOC_ACTV_CD"]).agg("sum")["SUM_DOC_CNT"]
```

which results in this grouped data:

```
DOC_ACC_DT  DOC_ACTV_CD
2015-07-01  BR              1
            PT              1
2015-07-02  BR              1
            PT              1
2015-07-06  BR              1
            PT              1
2015-07-08  BR              1
2015-07-09  AD              2
            PT              1
2015-07-13  AD             50
            BR             52
            PT              1
2015-07-14  AD              6
            BR              5
            PT              1
2015-07-16  BR              1
            PT              1
2015-07-23  AD             13
            BR             14
            PT              3
2015-07-27  BR              1
            PT              1
```

What I want to do now is simply plot by `DOC_ACTV_CD`. Please not that there are gaps between days so I'd have to fill in zero-values between days where nothing happened e.g.

```
2015-07-23  AD             13
            BR             14
            PT              3
2015-07-25  BR              1
            PT              1
```

would have to become

```
2015-07-23  AD             13
            BR             14
            PT              3
2015-07-24  AD              0
            BR              0
            PT              0
2015-07-25  AD              0
            BR              1
            PT              1
```

before I plot a time series for `AD`, `BR` and `PT` in one plot. What's the quickest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = user.groupby(["DOC_ACC_DT", "DOC_ACTV_CD"]).agg("sum")["SUM_DOC_CNT"]
df.unstack().resample('D').replace(np.nan,0).plot()
```

Comment: Thank you. It return warning, problem is with function [`fillna(0)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39452095/2901002).