# how to insert new row in pandas data frame at desired index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, resampling

I have a data frame which has missing dates

```
print data 

Date  Longitude  Latitude  Elevation  Max Temperature  \
4/11/1979  83.75  24.197701       238     44.769           20.007   
4/12/1979  83.75  24.197701       238     41.967           18.027   
4/13/1979  83.75  24.197701       238     43.053           20.549    
4/15/1979  83.75  24.197701       238     40.826           20.189
```

How do I insert `4/14/1979` at the `4th` row

print data

```
Date  Longitude  Latitude  Elevation  Max Temperature  \
4/11/1979  83.75  24.197701       238     44.769           20.007   
4/12/1979  83.75  24.197701       238     41.967           18.027   
4/13/1979  83.75  24.197701       238     43.053           20.549
4/14/1979  0.0    0.0             0       0.0              0.0
4/15/1979  83.75  24.197701       238     40.826           20.189
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert column `Date` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for resampling.

You can use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by `D` (`days`) and then need fill `NaN` to `0`, one posible solution is [`replace({np.nan:0})`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39452095/2901002):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

df = df.resample('D').replace({np.nan:0}).reset_index()
print (df)
        Date  Longitude   Latitude  Elevation     Max  Temperature
0 1979-04-11      83.75  24.197701      238.0  44.769       20.007
1 1979-04-12      83.75  24.197701      238.0  41.967       18.027
2 1979-04-13      83.75  24.197701      238.0  43.053       20.549
3 1979-04-14       0.00   0.000000        0.0   0.000        0.000
4 1979-04-15      83.75  24.197701      238.0  40.826       20.189
```

Comment: Is "Date" your index in this dataframe ?

Comment: Yes, I set it by `df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)`, but last I `.reset_index()` it.